# How to calculate the total time duration of concentration crossing a threshold multiple times?

Tags: r, time, threshold

Using R, I am trying to calculate the total time duration for each individual where this time duration is the time spent above certain threshold.

For example, in the plot below I have the concentration data for 3 subjects (ID), and I would like to find the time (x axis) spent above the blue dashed line for each individual. the data set structure would be something like:

```
head(dataset)
  ID time      CP
1  1  0.0 0.00000000
2  1  0.0 0.00000000
3  1  0.5 0.03759806
4  1  1.0 0.12523455
5  1  1.5 0.23483219
6  1  2.0 0.34820905
```

[*Solid lines represent the concentrations for 3 different subjects*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPim2.png)

I tried to use the following code:

```
library(data.table) 
TAbove<-setDT(dataset)[CP > .05, diff(range(time)), by = ID]
```

However,  this code that it calculates the time duration from first rise above dashed blue line to the last drop. For example for the green line ID, see the black line.

[image]

How can I write a code that takes into account the times where the concentrations drop below the dashed line, by excluding them. the final result would be a total time duration of all the times above the dashed blue line. like below

[image]

Comment: See `?rle`. Ignoring the multiple ids for the moment, having, say, `x = sin(seq(-3*pi, 3*pi, 0.1))` and computing `r = rle(x > threshold)`, the starting and end positions of successive `TRUE`s (i.e. `x > threshold`) are `s = cumsum(c(1, r$lengths))[r$values]` and `e = i + r$lengths[r$values] - 1`, respectively. Summing `time[e] - time[s]` should give the total time where `x > threshold`.

Comment: @alexis_laz Can you add your comment as an answer?  This solved the problem for me and I will upvote.  Think you just have 1 typo where `i` should be `s` when you define `e`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, thanks to rhole for providing the idea of how to solve the question.
the code below helped me do the analysis, however I had to add a variable called "Day", and then calculate the time duration per day. Here I used day because there is one interval per day. But you can adjust it according to your need.

```
#sub-setting by day
dataset$Day[dataset$time>=0 &dataset$time<24] <- "Day 1"
dataset$Day[dataset$time>=24 &dataset$time<48] <- "Day 2"
dataset$Day[dataset$time>=48 &dataset$time<72] <- "Day 3"
#per day#
TAbove<-setDT(dataset)[CP > .05, diff((time)), by = .(ID,Day)]
library(plyr)
# sum the time duration for each day per person
sumPerDay<-summarise(group_by(TAbove, ID,Day),
           sum=sum(V1))
# sum the time duration for ALL days per person
sumAll<-summarise(group_by(TAbove, ID),
                 sum=sum(V1))
```

Answer (score 3):

I think your solution is almost perfect, just leave out `range`. I tried the following on an extended dataset (added a few entries)

```
> dat <- fread("ID time      CP
+               1  0.0 0.00000000
+               1  0.0 0.00000000
+               1  0.5 0.03759806
+               1  1.0 0.12523455
+               1  1.5 0.23483219
+               1  2.0 0.34820905
+               1  3.0 0.5
+               2  0.0 0.5
+               2  0.5 0.01
+               2  1.0 0.2")
```

with the following result:

```
> dat[CP > .05, diff(time), by = ID]
   ID  V1
1:  1 0.5
2:  1 0.5
3:  1 1.0
4:  2 1.0
```

**Edit: Calculation with original data set**

Using the original data set

```
dataset <- fread("ID time      CP
                  1  0.0 0.00000000
                  1  0.0 0.00000000
                  1  0.5 0.03759806
                  1  1.0 0.12523455
                  1  1.5 0.23483219
                  1  2.0 0.34820905")
```

we get the following result:

```
> dataset[CP > .05, diff(time), by = ID]
   ID  V1
1:  1 0.5
2:  1 0.5
```

Comment: For some reason, the code is giving me different answer.     <blink>
        ID  V1
  1:  1 0.5
  2:  1 0.5
  3:  1 0.5
  4:  1 0.5
    </blink>

Comment: Maybe restarting your R session or updating to the newest version of `data.table` helps. Just double checked my solution and it works on my machine with the newest version of R, `data.table` and a fresh R session.

Comment: Sorry, tried it but still giving me different results. Could you please write the code you used?

Comment: Edited my answer with the calculation for the original data set provided by you. Time frames are correctly calculated between observations that have a `CP > 0.05`. Hope this helps!