# calculate time drug concentrations is above a certain threshold in R

Tags: r, time

I have a data set that contains the time vs drug concentration for several patients (repeated measures per patient) as shown below:

[image]

How can I calculate the time drug concentration remained above a certain threshold for every individual?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you want. Do you want the time between when the concentration rose above the threshold until when it fell beneath it? Do you plan to interpolate between data points to estimate the exact time, or are you happy just to use the integer times you have? If you plan to interpolate, what type of relationship are you expecting to see between time and concentration? Finally, you need to post your sample data as text not an image so that others can work with it.

Comment: To elaborate on @NickKennedy 's last sentence. Please use `dput` to create a text readable version of your data and paste it into your question. If your data is too long,  use something like `dput(head(data,16))`

Comment: Thanks,                                                                                                yes, I want to know when it rose and fell below the threshold. For example, if the threshold is 4, for individual 1 it rose above at 2 hours and remained above until hour 5, so from 2-5 hours the concentration was above the 4, so time above threshold is 3 hours. No, I do not want to interpolate between time points

Comment: This post might be helpful. [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38702109/how-to-calculate-the-total-time-duration-of-concentration-crossing-a-threshold-m)

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed.